# Windows 8 Metro Style Desktop Applications?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Windows 8 had released! I want to create a metro style DESKTOP application like GitHub-for-Windows(http://windows.github.com/).How can I develop this kind style? WPF,WinForm or others.
Does Microsoft supply solutions for Desktop Metro applications at Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Mahapps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)
It is exactly for what you want.

I have used it and I found it very easy to get in to.

**EDIT**

You could also have a look at the more recently released [Modern UI for WPF](http://mui.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thinks,Erno.I know little about Mahapps.Metro. But this solution is powered by third part company.I want to know much about that if Microsoft offers official Library that helps us to create an metro style DESKTOP application.I have install VS2012,but I didn't find what I want.If you konw more,Please tell me.Thinks again.

Comment: No, Microsoft doesn't supply a solution for this.

Comment: MahApps is still open source under MS-PL. Here is a screenshot from my [Wide](https://github.com/chandramouleswaran/Wide/tree/v0.1-alpha) project to create VS like applications.


Sample screen shots:

Visual studio 2012 style (still under development)
![VS2012 Style](https://raw.github.com/wiki/chandramouleswaran/Wide/Wide.png)

Comment: @HUANGLIWEN I added a new alternative to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this. But anyway, you can [check this out](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8)

Microsoft does provide Visual Studio Express for Windows 8.

Comment: Hello,AbhishekGirish. I know you are talking about MERTO APPS run on Metro Environment.But I want to know metro style apps work based on desktop or called 'Classic Desktop' which interface looks like Office 2013,Visual Studio 2012 and GitHub-for-Windows.Think you all the same.

Comment: @HUANGLIWEN Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 is not a Metro (Modern UI) App. It opens on the Desktop.